# How can i display only a text without an image in my flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I created a feature where users can upload image and upload description inform of text.
A user can choose to upload an image with description differently and can also upload only a description differently without an image. After uploading the text in firestore and query it to display in the user post it will return an error:

> Cached_image_widget.dart: Failed assertion: line 163 POS 16: 'imageUrl != null': is not true.

cachedNetworkImage method code:

```
Widget cachedNetworkImage(String mediaUrl) {
  return CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: mediaUrl,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    placeholder: (context, url) => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
    );
}
```

This is my code for the post image:

```
buildPostImage() {
       return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onDoubleTap: handleLikePost,
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                cachedNetworkImage(mediaUrl),
                showHeart ? Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 100.0, color: 
                Colors.grey[400]) :
                Text(''),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

this is code for the description:

```
 Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
               // color: Colors.grey[800],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0)
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text(
                  description,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 17.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: can you provide some of your code? it seems to be simple to solve, but we need to know how is the structure of your code.

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: can you also provide the code for your `cachedNetworkImage` method?

Comment: I have updated it as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the imageUrl is receiving null, to fix that you can do the following:

```
buildPostImage() {
       return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onDoubleTap: handleLikePost,
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                mediaUrl != null ? cachedNetworkImage(mediaUrl) : Container(),
                showHeart ? Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 100.0, color: 
                Colors.grey[400]) :
                Text(''),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: that's probably because you're using an expanded for that and it is filling all the available space, try using a flexible instead ;)